# I need a guidance which mapping strategy to use

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am writing a process for sending email notification. Currently I write the email notifications in a table with the following columns:

- email_notification_id => PK
- notification_id => the notification
- sender_id => User or Group object
- recipient_id => User or Group object

sender and recipient can be of type User or Group. Obviously at the moment I cannot have FKs for sender or recipient.

1) The first option is to use Any in the mapping and add two additional columns for the type.

2) The second option is to create 4 classes for each combination and map them using discriminator:

class1 => sender of type Group, recipient of type Group
class2 => sender of type Group, recipient of type User
class3 => sender of type User, recipient of type Group
class4 => sender of type User, recipient of type User

3) Other options?

What do you think about this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could also create a `EmailEntityBase` (or whatever better phrasing you may find) class, from which both `Group` and `User` will inherit.
then your `Notification` entity would refer to  `EmailEntityBase` sender and recipient properties.

Comment: Hey, This one would be great if User and group were in a single table. Also, I do not want to pollute these two entities with base class (this is .net project => single base class). 

Comment: I believe you can use table-per-class mapping strategy, and let nHib sort out the columns thing. see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993200/fluent-nhibernate-collection-table-per-subclass   P.S. If two classes have some sort of a common logical base, I wouldn't consider it 'pollution'. If the only common thing to User and Group is that they can send / receive notifications, than you're right.

Comment: The same question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhusers/7ytApniUiUo

Answer (score 1):

If it were me and I had control over the database I would change the two columns **sender_id** and **recipient_id** to **sender** and **recipients**.  These would be string fields that contain the raw email addresses you are intending to use.

This is just another way to do it.  Not necessarily the best as far as database design is concerned but simple from an implementation and mapping perspective.

Comment: Agreed, I would say that this solution is like solution 1, because you do not have any FK at all, but simpler.